# how to do a clean deployment in dev_appserver?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, caching

How to do a clean deployment into app-engine dev server?

I am using google app-engine java and command line tools (ant, ant runserver).

When I submit new request through chrome, I am getting response from my old code.

I am not sure where my old code was cached. Am I missing anything?

Checked following things,

1. class file timestamp, ~\app1\war\WEB-INF\classes
2. servlet-mapping
3. cache setting in jsp,
4. I am not able to locate, compiled .class file for .jsp

other details,

- app-engine java sdk 1.6.3.
- JAVA_HOME=C:\glassfish3\jdk7
- JRE_HOME=C:\glassfish3\jdk7\jre
- chrome (latest)
- windows vista

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are running the application twice via a zombie process? check using netstat -o (in the command line) which process is holding the port and kill it or just reboot.

Comment: Many thanks. that was really helpful.

yet don't know how I managed to run so many (30+) java processes.

I used to kill dev_appserver, using ctrl+c. After killing all java processes, now I am able to access latest version of my app.

Comment: I have added a ant target to solve this issue,

<target name="compile" depends="copyjars, kill-java-zombies"
...

  <target name="kill-java-zombies">
    <echo>Killing all java zombies...</echo>
    <exec executable="taskkill">
        <arg value="/IM"/>
        <arg value="java.exe"/>
    </exec>
  </target>
...